# Sphere packing in high dimensions and boundary conditions

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

The Minkowski lower bound for packing hyperspheres of unit radii in $\mathbb{R}^n$ states that the density of hyperspheres satisfies, for all $n\geq 2$
\begin{equation}
\Delta_n \geq \frac{\zeta(n)}{2^{n-1}},
\end{equation} 
where $\zeta(n) \rightarrow 1$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

My question is whether boundary conditions in the definition of density affect the asymptotic behavior of this bound. Any reasonable definition of density would be something like:
\begin{equation}
\Delta_n = \lim_{\rho \rightarrow \infty} \frac{N(\rho \mathscr{B}_n)}{\mu(\rho \mathscr{B}_n)},
\end{equation} 
where $\mathscr{B}_n$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$,  $\rho$ is a uniform scaling factor for $\mathscr{B}_n$, $\mu(\cdot)$ indicates measure, and $N(\cdot)$ indicates the number of balls.

The Minkowski bound  implies that, as $n \rightarrow \infty$
\begin{equation}
\Delta_n \geq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + o(1).
\end{equation} 
Does this asymptotic behavior hold independent of boundary conditions on $\mathscr{B}_n$, or should $\mathscr{B}_n$ be some "regular" shape, like a ball or a box, or some other convex shape?

What if $\rho = \rho(n)$, for example the dimension grows at a faster rate than the scaling factor used to define the density, does the same asymptotic behavior hold?

Comment: Well, take a look at SPLAG pages 14-18 (in the first edition). I would say your question is not known. Anyway, Sphere Packings, Lattices, and Groups, by Conway and Sloane.

Comment: Can you clarify what is SPLAG? So far I could not find what definition of density is used, most authors simply state "the portion of the space occupied by spheres". I am wondering what is known regarding boundary condition and how this influences the Minkowski lower bound.

Comment: see http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b15175879~S1

Comment: I could not find anything regarding boundary conditions in Conway and Sloane. I edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.